# split csv file into multiple file based on field in Java

Tags: java, file, csv, amazon-s3

We need to process large CSV file stored on S3 generated on daily basis.
We want to split the data into small files based on category given in each line. So we are reading line by line and process it with streaming to avoid memory issue. I am able to split the file into multiple files based on the row count but I am not able to split it based on category because rows are not sequential.

Can someone point me in the right direction, how to write data into multiple files based on category while parsing the large file?

Comment: Why not just keep the category files open until you are done? For example, keep a Map<Category, OutputStream> (or whatever) and as you parse each line and determine the category, you look up the right stream and append it. When your stream lookup returns null, you know this is the first line for that category - you open the stream and put it in the Map. When you are done, iterate over the Map entries and close the streams.

Comment: I was thinking in same direction but not sure about io limitation because I have 100 odd categories and file contains 30 days data.

Comment: I need to split based on category and date.

Comment: 3000 files doesn't sound scary. I would try it. Worst case, it is too many open files for your ssytem you have to process in two stages: 1) break the one file into 100 category files and 2) break each category file into 30 day files. Personally, I would expect it will be totally fine all in one go.

Comment: @Rob thanks for the input, 3000 files for 1 customer and we have thousands of customers and we want to process the data in parallel.

Comment: You really should reread your question and edit so that it reflects what you are really trying to do. "Multiple" files is very different from millions of files. You may want to consider AWS EMR - the map step would do your customer+category+date sorting and reduce would simply be writing out the files.